# No sound through headset - only mic is working

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-8.1, headphones

I noticed that no sound is being played to my headphones. The laptop has a conexant sound card together with the sounds apps provided. But the thing is that I also noticed that now instead of one playback device - 2 are presented: speakers and headphones. And while speakers do play sound nicely - even test sound are not played through headphone output. Also, headphone output does not have a jack assigned to it, while speakers have L R Rear panel Analog Jack(my laptop does not have a jack on the back - only on the right).

Also - my headphones have a mic as well - and when I plug it in - the mic is working(using top panel digital jack),but the headphones themselves are not. And laptop is recognizing when audio device is plugged in. And I checked the headset on other devices - the headphones are working.

I have tried updating drivers, rolling back drivers and completely uninstalling drivers and then restarting - nothing helped.

I imagine that I somehow need to reconfigure the jack configuration just have no idea how and where.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

EDIT: Testing headphone playback device returns an error. This device is visible even when headphones are not plugged in.

Comment: Plug the headphones into something else. Do they work elsewhere? Headphones do NOT need drivers. Sound cards do but I'd suspect that is not your problem. It sounds like you have a short in your headphones (which is VERY common with headphones because people don't take proper care of them).

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP - i tested my headphones on other devices. Another laptop and an iPod to be exact. They are working fine. Jack config has changed. SmartAudio used to show "right" side port, now it shows "left". And number of playback devices changed as well

Comment: can you set the headphones as the default playback device?

Comment: I do but that changes nothing